# Grammar: Transformation

Tags: sentence-structure, transformation, types-of-sentences

Is it possible to transform all sentences into 'Simple, Compound & Complex' from one another, or are there any exceptions?

Kindly clarify.

*Besides music, he learnt karate.*
What are the Compound & Complex versions of it?

I know you. (Simple)
I know who you are. (Complex)

Here, a Simple Sentence is changed to a Complex Sentence.

What is its Compound?

Comment: @JamesK,  I am asking about changing one type into the other type. Can all sentences be presented in all the three types, namely Simple, Compound & Complex? Or, are there any exceptional cases?

Comment: @JamesK, Well, what is the complex type of the sentence: Besides music, he also learns karate.

Comment: Where are you getting your definition of simple and complex from?

Comment: @JamesK I agree, I don't understand the question either.

Comment: @PeterJennings, Can you define the terms Simple, Compound &  Complex types of Sentences' from your own perspective, please?

Comment: Please look up what you are asking about before asking about it.

Comment: @BaskaranSoundararajan The short answer is "No I cannot". As a native BrE speaker I've never thought about it nor been taught such minutiae of the language. That's why I was asking you for your definition. You must have a definition somewhere in order to ask the question.

Answer (score 1):

You don't understand what "Transformation" means.

It is never possible to transform a simple sentence into a compound sentence, or complex sentence.

A grammatical "transformation" is where you modify a sentence to get a new sentence with the same, or predictably changed meaning. It is a regular change following some rule.

So it is possible to transform a present tense sentence to past tense.

> I watch TV  -> I watched TV (transformed to past tense)

It is possible to transform an active voice sentence to passive voice

> I watch TV -> TV is watched by me (transformed to passive)

These are transformations.  They follow a regular rule and they have a predictable effect on the meaning.

It might be possible to rephrase a simple sentence (a sentence that contains one clause) as a complex sentence (a sentence that contains a main and a subordinate clause) or as a compound sentence (a sentence with two main clauses, joined by "and" or "but")

In your example "I know you" is a simple sentence.  "I know who you are" is a complex sentence. The meanings of these sentences are similar, but not quite the same.  **This is not a transformation**.  It is a rephrasing.  It doesn't follow any general rule.  You can't say "I watch what TV is".  That is nonsence.

Now, "I watch TV" could be rephrased as (1) "I watch the programmes that are shown on TV".  Or you could say (2) "I have a TV and I watch it."  That complex(1) and compound(2) sentence are somewhat similar in meaning to the simple sentence **But this is not a transformation**.